# How to delete elements from sql database based on a date using c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have this Service that works to delete one (1) row from the database (Sorry for any lingo errors.):

```
public bool DeleteSchedulesFromDate(DateTime objDateTime)
    {
        var result = _db.Schedules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AppointmentDateEnd <= objDateTime);            
        if (result != null)
        {
            _db.Schedules.Remove(result);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This as the calling function:

```
private void DeleteSchedules(string dtEnd)
{
    deleteScheduleDate = dtEnd;

    DateTime _dtEnd;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dtEnd, out _dtEnd))
    {
        var result = @Service.DeleteSchedulesFromDate(_dtEnd);

        schedules.Clear();
        schedules = Service.GetSchedules();

        if (result)
        {
            this.ShouldRender();
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I change it to delete all rows that matches the passed DateTime object?

I have tried :

- to change it to a List, but then the bool doesn't work.
- set a loop in the Service, but can't make it run correctly.
- set a loop in the function call, but can't make it work either.
- to google and look up other posts on SO, but found no match.

Comment: Replace "FirstOrDefault" with "Where".  The use RemoveAll() instead of Remove().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of searching for the first match with `FirstOrDefault` you should get all valid result into a List (`Where` + `ToList`) and delete all of them (`RemoveRange`)

```
var result = _db.Schedules.Where(x => x.AppointmentDateEnd <= objDateTime).ToList();            
if (result.Any())
{
    _db.Schedules.RemoveRange(result);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```